# How to react to javascript CustomEvent from Blazor webassembly component

Tags: blazor-webassembly

I have a Canvas element which has some custom functionality written in Javascript. I'm trying to create a wrapper for this functionality in a Blazor Webassembly component.

The Javascript code generates custom events using the `dispatchEvent` method:

```
const event = new CustomEvent("uvrectadded", {
            bubbles: true,
            detail: { uvrect: uvr }
});
const result = this.canvas.dispatchEvent(event);
```

How to I listen for this event in a Blazor serverside component? I have tried the following:

```
<canvas id="map-canvas" @uvrectadded="OnUVRectAdded"></canvas>

@code{
    private void OnUVRectAdded(EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Blazor: ONUVRectAdded");
    }
}
```

In the code above, the directive is not compiled, but I can't find out how to register an event directive.

Aside: I have also tried raising a `change` event from the Javascript component, and this does get registered by the Blazor code with an `@onchange` directive, however, an exception is thrown saying the system cannot deserialize the event.

Comment: Did you ever manage to find an answer to this? I am looking for the same thing. The `EventHandler` attribute is also not helping, as I don't know what I'm supposed to do with it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Blazor listen to javascript event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67594699/blazor-listen-to-javascript-event)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Blazor, you can register a directive using an `EventHandlerAttribute` like this:

```
[EventHandler("onuvrectadded", typeof(EventArgs))]
public static class EventHandlers
{
}
```

However, I am having some issues deserializing the `detail` property of the `CustomEvent`.

Comment: The only way I've found so far to get custom data into Blazor from an event is by using onchange + a value property on a Web Component. So you could wrap your canvas in a web component and expose a change event and a value attribute.

Comment: Relevant Blazor source code: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/d827c653b787c07de908240b7746ce34d3e6271e/src/Components/Shared/src/WebEventData.cs#L62 and https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/d827c653b787c07de908240b7746ce34d3e6271e/src/Components/Web.JS/src/Rendering/EventForDotNet.ts#L10

Comment: You can register, but as in my example, it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Im struggling too. I can see the JS event being raised (have added a JS listener to check is actually raised).

I have registered the event, and defined the C# part of it as well.

```
  [EventHandler("oncustomjsevent", typeof(CustomJSEventArgs), enableStopPropagation: true, enablePreventDefault: true)]
    public static class EventHandlers
    {
        // This static class doesn't need to contain any members. It's just a place where we can put
        // [EventHandler] attributes to configure event types on the Razor compiler. This affects the
        // compiler output as well as code completions in the editor.
    }

    public class CustomJSEventArgs : System.EventArgs
    {
        // Data for these properties will be supplied by custom JavaScript logic
        public string EventData { get; set; }
    }
```

But cant get Blazor to see the event anywhere. Have tried adding to divs, buttons, labels, etc still doesnt work., eg.

```
   <Button @oncustomjsevent="OnLinkClick" />

 private void OnLinkClick(CustomJSEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        throw new InvalidCastException(eventArgs.EventData);
        var x = 1; 
    }
```