# Blazor listen to javascript event

Tags: javascript, .net, blazor, interop, webassembly

I have a javascript event called Hello:

```js
addEventListener('hello', function () {
  alert("event listener");
})
```

and, in another javascript function, I raise the event:

```js
let event = new Event("hello", { bubbles: true });
document.dispatchEvent(event);
```

What I want to do now is let the event trigger in a javascript function.
Blazor should listen to the event, not javascript calling a Blazor method.

Hope anyone can assist me.

Regards me,

Comment: What version of .NET are you using?

Comment: i'm using .Net 5.0

Comment: I only asked because .NET 6 preview 2 introduces custom event types to Blazor. Until then, if you want to handle a custom event like yours, you would need to "trick" blazor by having your custom event handler dispatch a standard event that your are listening for, e.g. have something like `<div id='foo' @onchange=HandleHello></div>` in your Blazor code, then in your JS code dispatch a `change` event to `foo` whenever you capture  a `hello` event.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. i can still change to version 6 prev 2
i just started building the app.
What is your sugestion?

Comment: Go to .NET 6 preview 3, then you can do this: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/asp-net-core-updates-in-net-6-preview-2/#support-for-custom-event-arguments-in-blazor

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For custom events, you will need to manually utilize [JavaScript/.NET interoperability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-dotnet-from-javascript?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

Using the [Instance Method Call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-dotnet-from-javascript?view=aspnetcore-5.0#instance-method-call) method:

> - Pass the .NET instance by reference to JavaScript:
>
>   - Make a static call to DotNetObjectReference.Create.
>   - Wrap the instance in a DotNetObjectReference instance and call Create on the DotNetObjectReference instance. Dispose of DotNetObjectReference objects (an example appears later in this section).
> - Invoke .NET instance methods on the instance using the `invokeMethod` or `invokeMethodAsync` functions. The .NET instance can also be passed as an argument when invoking other .NET methods from JavaScript.

#### Example

Note, this is a very simplified example. You probably want to add a few things; start by `IDisposable` on your interop classes [to avoid memory leaks](https://blazor-university.com/javascript-interop/calling-dotnet-from-javascript/lifetimes-and-memory-leaks/).

1. In C#, create a helper class to manage the interop:

```cs
public class CustomEventHelper
{
    private readonly Func<EventArgs, Task> _callback;

    public CustomEventHelper(Func<EventArgs, Task> callback)
    {
        _callback = callback;
    }

    [JSInvokable]
    public Task OnCustomEvent(EventArgs args) => _callback(args);
}

public class CustomEventInterop : IDisposable
{
    private readonly IJSRuntime _jsRuntime;
    private DotNetObjectReference<CustomEventHelper> Reference;

    public CustomEventInterop(IJSRuntime jsRuntime)
    {
        _jsRuntime = jsRuntime;
    }

    public ValueTask<string> SetupCustomEventCallback(Func<EventArgs, Task> callback)
    {
        Reference = DotNetObjectReference.Create(new ScrollEventHelper(callback));
        // addCustomEventListener will be a js function we create later
        return _jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("addCustomEventListener", Reference);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Reference?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

2. In a Blazor component, add an instance of the interop class (`Interop`) and add a local method as a callback (`HandleCustomEvent`):

```cs
private CustomEventInterop Interop { get; set; }

protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender) {
    if (!firstRender)
    {
        return;
    }
    Interop = new(JS);
    await Interop.SetupCustomEventCallback(args => HandleCustomEvent(args));
    HasRendered = true;
}

private void HandleCustomEvent(EventArgs args) {
    // ... handle custom event here
}
```

3. In JavaScript, add a method that references the `DotNetObjectReference` and can call the interop in C#:

```js
function addCustomEventListener(dotNetObjectRef) {
  document.addEventListener('hello', (event) => {
    // Calls a method by name with the [JSInokable] attribute (above)
    dotNetObjectRef.invokeMethodAsync('OnCustomEvent')
  });
}
```

If using TypeScript, you might check out this [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/18902#issuecomment-585987887).

Comment: I Only want to a subscibe to a event created in javascript.
There are no button or ui elements used. 
IT's like the observer patern

Comment: Yeah, you have to use JS Interop for that. As of .NET 5, this is the only way to listen for custom events in blazor.

Comment: alright :), will look into it. 
I'm using it to create a interop with pixijs :)

Comment: Ps: What more thing could be added? Example?

Comment: Depends on what you want to do. You might want a way to tell JS to stop sending events after the component disposes, for example. I'd ask that in a new question though; bit out of scope for this post.

Comment: This is not the way to create custom event in Blazor. @Teckniel, you should follow the advice made by Mister Magoo

Comment: @enet unless you are using .NET 6 preview, JS interop is the best way to handle real custom events. mrmagoo's hack may work, but it's still that: a hack.

Comment: On the contrary, yours is a hack, his is the native Blazor way to create custom events.

Comment: Let's not be confused, moving to .NET6 P2/3 and using a custom event type is the "blazor way" *but is still in preview*. Anything else is a workaround. I wouldn't personally use this method but it will certainly work and is a solid way to do it.

Comment: Exactly, and this isn't the only way to use JS interop to achieve an event listener in Blazor. Until .NET 6 ships, I think JS interop is the most robust way to solve the problem from the question. It could even be expanded to accept a serializable payload from js, which you can't do with the `@onclick` workaround. If you don't need anything fancy, then @mister magoo has given you a fine workaround as well. I suspect more appealing answers will arrive when .NET 6 ships.

Comment: @Connor Switching to .Net 6.0 prev 3 since it is the best way to implement i guess, for long time support. and also to have a more style of sperate of concern.

Regards and thanks fr the help!

Comment: Even now, after .Net6 shipped, I cant make the .net6 way work.

Answer (score 10):

For anyone wondering the solution proposed by @Mister Magoo is no longer a preview for .NET 6 and is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/event-handling?view=aspnetcore-6.0#custom-event-arguments-1) with some exemples.

In a nutshell :

Create a C# class with the EventHandlerAttribute :

```
[EventHandler("oncityclicked", typeof(CustomSelectionCityEventArgs),
    enableStopPropagation: true, enablePreventDefault: true)]
public static class EventHandlers
{
}

public class CustomSelectionCityEventArgs: EventArgs
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}
```

Add JS inside `./wwwroot/index.html` and after `<script src="_framework/blazor.webview.js" autostart="false"></script>` :

```
<script>
    Blazor.registerCustomEventType('cityclicked', {
        createEventArgs: event => {
            return {
                id: event.detail
            };
        }
    });
</script>
```

In you razor :

```
@code {
    private void HandleCityClicked(CustomSelectionCityEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Bouep");
    }
}

<div id="CarteLeaflet" @oncityclicked="HandleCityClicked"></div>
```

And finally in the JS you can dispatch the event :

```
function OnMarkerClick(pId) {
    const event = new CustomEvent('cityclicked', {
        bubbles: true,
        detail: pId
    });
    document.getElementById('CarteLeaflet').dispatchEvent(event);
}
```

Don't make the same mistake as me, the event name in the C# should start with "on" (JS : "cityclicked", C# : "oncityclicked").