# Blazor - using onkeydown with TinyMCE

Tags: blazor, tinymce

Does anyone have an example on how to use OnKeyDown with TinyMCE? I have looked through the docs and cant seem to find an example of this working with blazor

I have tried looking at the documentation and have only found non-blazor examples. I am using the tiny-MCE NuGet package.

Example done with JS objects
https://www.tiny.cloud/blog/keypress-event/
In this article you can see how the library has an object that is passed in that "configures" the editor.

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: "textarea#editor",
  plugins: "a11ychecker advcode advlist advtable anchor autocorrect autolink autosave editimage fullscreen image link linkchecker lists media mediaembed pageembed powerpaste searchreplace table template tinymcespellchecker typography visualblocks wordcount",
  toolbar: "undo redo | styles | bold italic underline strikethrough | align | table link image media pageembed | bullist numlist outdent indent | spellchecker a11ycheck typography code | fullscreen",
  setup: (editor) => { editor.on('keydown', (e) => { } }
```

However with the Blazor TinyMCE library you pass in a C# dictionary<string, string> and they do not have an example how you would use a event with Blazor TinyMCE.

```
<Editor
  Conf="@editorConf"
/>

@code {
  private Dictionary<string. object> editorConf = new Dictionary<string, object>{
    {"toolbar", "undo redo | bold italic"},
    {"width", 400}
  };
}
```

Comment: Could you post an example (maybe from the docs) about how onkeydown is configured in the library? Once you've figured out how to handle the event in the library then you need to figure out how to send that event back to Blazor. There are plenty of examples of how to do that. Relevant question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67594699/blazor-listen-to-javascript-event

Comment: I have added specific examples of how this works in Javascript, please see the updated question.

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally, your problem is that you want to be able to invoke a Blazor function from a client-side event.

Luckily Blazor comes with both client-server and server-client communication methods.

### 1. Create a JavaScript initializer

According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/startup?view=aspnetcore-8.0#javascript-initializers):

> JavaScript (JS) initializers execute logic before and after a Blazor
> app loads. JS initializers are useful in the following scenarios:
>
> - Customizing how a Blazor app loads.
> - Initializing libraries before Blazor starts up.
> - Configuring Blazor settings.

Create the following file:

`wwwroot/{PACKAGE ID/ASSEMBLY NAME}.lib.module.js`

For example, if your Blazor web project is called `MyProject.csproj`, the file would be called `MyProject.lib.module.js`.

### 2. Register a custom event

You will be binding your components to custom events. An example of this with a built-in event is `@onclick`.

Inside the new JS file add the code to register a custom event:

```js
export function afterWebStarted(blazor) {
  // give the event a specific name
  blazor.registerCustomEventType('tinymcekeydown', {    
    createEventArgs: function (event) {
      return {
        // TODO: set meaningful args here
        myKey: event.detail.myKey
      };
    }
  });
}
```

**Event registration differs between WebAssembly and Server, so check the docs.**

### 3. Create C# classes for your custom event args

```cs
public class EventHandlerTinyMceKeyDownEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    // TODO: add meaningful args here to match the JS event

    public string? MyKey { get; set; }
}
```

### 4. Wire up the custom events using an EventHandler

Create a C# class with the following rules (from the docs):

> - In order for the compiler to find the [EventHandler] class, it must be placed into a C# class file (.cs), making it a normal top-level
>   class.
> - Mark the class public.
> - The class doesn't require members.
> - The class must be called "EventHandlers" in order to be found by the Razor compiler.
> - Place the class under a namespace specific to your app.
> - Import the namespace into the Razor component (.razor) where the event is used.

Add an event handler attribute that corresponds to your custom event.

```cs
[EventHandler("ontinymcekeydown", typeof(EventHandlerTinyMceKeyDownEventArgs), 
enableStopPropagation: true, enablePreventDefault: true)]
public static class EventHandlers
{
}
```

In my implementation I place the `EventHandlers` class and my event args classes in the same file for convenience, and in a separate project for reusability, but obviously you can put them wherever you wish - as long as you meet the requirements.

### 4. Bind the event

You can now bind to your custom event just like any other event.

```html
<div id="my-tinymcecontainer" @ontinymcekeydown="@OnKeyDown">

</div>

@code {
  private void OnKeyDown(EventHandlerTinyMceKeyDownEventArgs args)
  {
    // TODO: handle the event
  }
}
```

### 5. Trigger the event

We've created all this boilerplate, but still have nothing to trigger the event itself.

In my example above I have bound the custom event to a container that I made up for the purposes of this example. For you to handle events on that container you're going to need to also fire events on that container.

In my implementation (handling drilldown events in a third-party charting library) I call the JS method to build the chart from my razor component, passing in a reference to the container HTML element, and then trigger events on that container to complete the circle.

For the purpose of finishing this example, I'm going to just grab a reference to the container using the id. In real code you would want a better approach.

```js
function handleKeyDown() {
  const el = document.GetElementById('my-tinymcecontainer');
  const event = new CustomEvent('tinymcekeydown', {
    detail: {
        key: 'Hello, World!'
    }
  });
  el.dispatchEvent(event);  
}
```

Full docs:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/event-handling?view=aspnetcore-8.0#custom-event-arguments